# All objects in a JSON list are deserializing as null C#

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am creating a game in the Unity game engine and while trying to load some JSON into some objects, I have encountered an issue. When I deserialize the JSON object, one of the object's fields, `Attributes`, which is a list of `Character_Attribute` objects, is being filled with `null`. The number of nulls is correct but it isn't loading the data correctly.

This is an example of the JSON that I am trying to parse:

```
{
"Name":"Test Character 1",
"Location_ID":1,
"Attributes":[
  {"Attribute_Type":0,"Base_Value":10,"Current_Value":10},
  {"Attribute_Type":1,"Base_Value":7,"Current_Value":7},
  {"Attribute_Type":2,"Base_Value":5,"Current_Value":5}
]
}
```

And these are the classes I am trying to load it into:

```
public class Character_Data
{
    public string Name;
    public int Location_ID;
    public List<Character_Attribute> Attributes;
}

[Serializable]
public class Character_Attribute : ScriptableObject
{
    public ATTRIBUTES Attribute_Type;
    public int Base_Value;
    public int Current_Value;
}
```

`ATTRIBUTES` is a simple enum.

This is the code I am using to deserialize the JSON, where json_string is the JSON from above:

```
Character_Data data = JsonUtility.FromJson<Character_Data>(json_string);
```

All of the elements of `data.Attributes` are `null`. All other properties are loading fine. Is this happening because `Character_Attribute` is a `ScriptableObject`? If so, why is that and is there any way to get around this or am I going to have to make an intermediary class to load the JSON into and then move all that data into `Character_Attribute` afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I created the classes and tried to deserialize the json string to `Character_Data` object

```
public class Character_Data
{
    public string Name;
    public int Location_ID;
    public List<Character_Attribute> Attributes;
}

[Serializable]
public class Character_Attribute : ScriptableObject
{
    public ATTRIBUTES Attribute_Type;
    public int Base_Value;
    public int Current_Value;

    public override string ClassName => string.Empty;
}
public enum ATTRIBUTES
{
    dev = 1,
    test = 2,
    stage = 3
}
```

As you mentioned ATTRIBUTES is an enum. I had to add my own enum values.
To implement the `ScriptableObject`, I installed `ScriptableObjectFramework` Nuget package.

However the difference I see in my implementation is, while implementing `ScriptableObjectFramework` abstract class, the `Character_Attribute` class has to implement an `override` property i.e.

```
public override string ClassName => string.Empty;
```

(I assigned string.Empty to ClassName).

You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` Nuget package to serialization or deserialization.

Below is my sample implementation:

```
var _object = new Character_Data
        {
            Name = "Test Character 1",
            Location_ID = 1,
            Attributes = new List<Character_Attribute>
            {
                new Character_Attribute { Attribute_Type = ATTRIBUTES.dev, Base_Value = 10, Current_Value = 10 },
                new Character_Attribute { Attribute_Type = ATTRIBUTES.test, Base_Value = 7, Current_Value = 7 },
                new Character_Attribute { Attribute_Type = ATTRIBUTES.stage, Base_Value = 5, Current_Value = 5 }
            }
        };
        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_object);
        Character_Data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Character_Data>(jsonString);
```

Namespaces I had to use:

```
using EcmaScript.NET;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

add serialize to main class too, and change enum to int

```
[Serializable]
public class Character_Data
{
    public string Name;
    public int Location_ID;
    public List<Character_Attribute> Attributes;
}

[Serializable]
public class Character_Attribute : ScriptableObject
{
    public int Attribute_Type;
    public int Base_Value;
    public int Current_Value;
}
```

if it is still not working properly install Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity
https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity#readme and use it